# How do I play a random music track one after the other on my blogger page?

Tags: javascript, html, blogger

I want my blogger page to play a random music track and when a track ends have it followed by another randomly chosen music track.

Here is what I tried:

```
<html>
<body>
<div id="soundtrack"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
var a = Math.random()*3;
a = Math.floor(a);

if(a==0)
{
    document.getElementById('soundtrack')
        .innerHTML="<audio autoplay><source src='s0000.mp3' type='audio/mp3'>Your browser does not support the audio element.</audio>";
}
if(a==1)
{
    alert(a);
    document.getElementById('soundtrack')
        .innerHTML="<audio autoplay><source src='s0001.mp3' type='audio/mp3'>Your browser does not support the audio element.</audio>";
}
if(a==2)
{
     document.getElementById('soundtrack')
          .innerHTML="<audio autoplay><source src='s0002.mp3' type='audio/mp3'>Your browser does not support the audio element.</audio>";
}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: But keep in mind that autoplaying music on websites is almost always irritiating and can make visitors leave your page as soon as anything begins to play.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use an [`ended`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Media_events) audio event handler

Try this.

```html
<html>
<body>
Random Audio Demo
<div >
<audio id="soundtrack" autoplay>
<source src='https://archive.org/download/kkkfffbird_yahoo_Beep_201607/beep.mp3' type='audio/mp3'>
Your browser does not support the audio element.</audio>

</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

var audio = document.getElementById('soundtrack'),
    music = [
        'https://archive.org/download/kkkfffbird_yahoo_Beep_201607/beep.mp3',
        'https://archive.org/download/Beep_7/beep.mp3',
        'https://archive.org/download/beep-07/beep-07.mp3'
    ];

audio.addEventListener('ended', function(e) {
    var r = Math.floor(Math.random()*3);

    audio.src = music[r];

});

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
function play(){
    var a = Math.random()*3;
    a=Math.floor(a);

    if(a==0)
    {document.getElementById('soundtrack').innerHTML="<audio autoplay><source src='https://archive.org/download/lohkungz_s0001/lohkungz_s0001.mp3' type='audio/mp3'>Your browser does not support the audio element.</audio>";}
    if(a==1)
    {alert(a); document.getElementById('soundtrack').innerHTML="<audio autoplay><source src='s0001.mp3' type='audio/mp3'>Your browser does not support the audio element.</audio>";}
    if(a==2)
    {document.getElementById('soundtrack').innerHTML="<audio autoplay><source src='s0002.mp3' type='audio/mp3'>Your browser does not support the audio element.</audio>";}

    var aud = document.getElementById('soundtrack').getElementsByTagName('audio');
    aud[0].onended = function() {
        play();
    };

}    
play();
    </script>
```

https://www.w3schools.com/TAGs/av_event_ended.asp

Answer (score 0):

You can see the below code,it may help you. Its sample code, you can add your correct mp3 files and use.

```js
musics = ['https://archive.org/download/lohkungz_s0001/lohkungz_s0001.mp3','https://archive.org/download/lohkungz_s0001/lohkungz_s0002.mp3','https://archive.org/download/lohkungz_s0001/lohkungz_s0003.mp3','https://archive.org/download/lohkungz_s0001/lohkungz_s0004.mp3'];
var aud = document.getElementById("music_palyer");
aud.onended = function() {
    console.log("The audio has ended");
 var a = Math.random()*musics.length;
 a=Math.floor(a);
 aud.src=musics[a];
 console.log(aud.src);
 aud.load();
```

```html
<div id="soundtrack">
<audio id="music_palyer" autoplay controls="controls"><source src='https://archive.org/download/lohkungz_s0001/lohkungz_s0001.mp3' type='audio/mp3'>Your browser does not support the audio element.</audio>
</div>
```